# Proxies bound to runtime in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started today getting my nose into proxies within JavaScript.

I created a simple proxy example for me and it works fine. Then I tested sending the proxy object to a different service within the application.

When the other service received the object, it just got transformed into a normal object without the custom behaviors of the proxy.

Since I'm new to it, my question is: is there a way to keep the custom behavior for the proxy object when transporting it outside of the source code where it got created?

Comment: What do you mean by "*transporting it outside of the source code where it got created*"? How did you "*send the proxy object to a different service within the application*"? If you send the *object*, it will work, if you serialise and deserialise it, then it won't.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Well what i meant with transporting is via a http request. I create the proxy object in service A, expose it via a get route and then request it from service B. When i get it in service B its a normal native Object instead of a proxy Object with costum behavior.

Comment: No, you cannot send living objects (including references and function code with closures) via HTTP. When serialising to JSON or something, you have a string not a proxy any more. You will need to explicitly create a new proxy in the other environment. Notice that this behaviour is completely normal and has nothing to do with proxies specifically.